# Google Maps Javascript map center update

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

All,

I am by no means a JavaScript programmer, mostly reusing/re-purposing snippets from here and there to accomplish things. I'm currently trying to work around a Google maps limitation, which is that the maps aren't styleable (AFAICT) unless you roll your own. I have a working HTML page, which contains a Google map, which correctly uses the Google maps styles and geolocation to set the map center to the user's location.

My question:

How can I keep the map centered on the user's location if their location changes while the page is open?

Search as I may I have been unable to find an example where the geolocation is updated through JavaScript. It could be that this isn't possible, it could be that Google's API documentation is weak, or possibly my Google-fu stinks. Possibly all three.

My code (taken almost verbatim from the Google Maps docs):

```html
 <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map, infoWindow;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 38.391677, lng: -97.661646},
          zoom: 17,
          styles: [...]
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.'); 
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
    </script>
  <script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=********************************&callback=initMap">
</script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

To detect changes in geolocation you can use the [watchPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) method. (Not supported in all browsers though).

You can then call [setCenter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.setCenter) when you have a new set of co-ordinates, and it will centre the map for you.

There's a [blog post here](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/using-html5-geolocation-to-show-current-location-with-google-maps-api) that seems to describe exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the initial setting of the center to the current location works, you could simply wrap the code in a setInterval call to repeatedly set the center every few seconds:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  setInterval(function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.'); 
      infoWindow.open(map);
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  }, 1000); // 1000 = number of milliseconds after which to repeat the call, i.e. 1 second
} else {
  // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
  handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
}
```

I'm not sure, if you really want the infoWindow and error message to be displayed on every call, but the basics are there.